# multiple rows using inline-block and percentage width

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

within a jquery mobile popup I would like to show five links per rows.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <a href="#popup1" id="btn1" data-role="button" data-rel="popup">button 1</a>
    <a href="#popup2" id="btn2" data-role="button" data-rel="popup">button 2</a>

    <div data-role="popup" id="popup1" class="ui-content">
        <a href="#">111</a>
        <a href="#">222</a>
        <a href="#">333</a>
        <a href="#">444</a>
        <a href="#">555</a>
        <a href="#">666</a>
        <a href="#">777</a>
        <a href="#">888</a>
        <a href="#">999</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popup2" class="ui-content">
        <a href="#">111</a>
        <a href="#">222</a>
        <a href="#">333</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%
}
```

When I click button 1 popup correctly shows 9 links splitted into two rows;
Click on the second button, instead, displays three links all attached. Why?

All can be viewed in http://jsfiddle.net/5EwTb/3/

Thanks.

Comment: You need to set a min-width of the popup. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Xx6wk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the links in div `data-role="content"` and remove `.ui-content` from popup div. then you need to set a `width` to content div.

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popup2">
  <div data-role="content">
    <a href="#">111</a>
    <a href="#">222</a>
    <a href="#">333</a>
  </div>
</div>

.ui-popup .ui-content {
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Xx6wk/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the white spaces that get generated between the `inline-block` elements - they add to the 20% and push the last one (out of the 5) to the next line.

- So it works if you eliminate the spaces/line-breaks between the anchors in your markup: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5EwTb/9/)
- To set this straight you can see some techniques here:
  **[How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)**

Comment: Thanks Martin. Your demo seems to have a little problem with button two because it has the same problem. However I have corrected my html with yours advices to avoid extra space between inline-blok.